# Can't seem to use SMPageControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, custom-controls, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to use SMPageControl, I've downloaded and added the h,m classes and I drag a UIView and set it's custom class to SMPageControl but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas about why wouldn't that work? I've also downloaded the sample project and dragged one of the UIViews that works there to my ViewController but it doesn't work.

SMPageControl: https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/SMPageControl

Comment: mind sharing some code?

Comment: @KunalBalani The thing is there's no code involved. The only thing I do is drag a UIView and set the custom class to the class needed and then after hooking up the only code i write is this `self.smPageControl.numberOfPages = 10;`

Comment: @BlueGene did you properly hook up the self.smPageControl outlet in IB?

Comment: @JerryJones I'm using storyborad, so I hooked smPageControl to my ViewController (Reference outlet) `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet SMPageControl *smPageControl;`

Comment: I'm a little at a loss, the only other thing I can think of is to consider when you set the number of pages. I don't use storyboards much, but with IB the view has to have been created before accessing views hooked to outlets in the nib. Can you set a breakpoint before you set the number pages and run `po self.smPageControl` in the debugger?

Comment: @JerryJones I tried moving the numberOfPages = 10 to `viewDidAppear` but with no use, this is the po results: `<SMPageControl: 0x8a4a1b0; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 219; 320 36); autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8f7dd20>>` Am I doing something wrong? I'm just adding a UIView and setting it to your class, and then setting the page count. anything else I should have done which I didn't?

Comment: @JerryJones Ok this is really embarrassing but the reason I couldn't see the control is because its almost transparent and my background color is white and you just can't see it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default appearance of SMPageControl is almost transparent and my background was white and thats why I couldn't see the control on my view.